# Function to find all the links on a webpage using java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find broken links on a webpage and I am using:

```
List<WebElement> var = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

which only finds elements on a current web page but I also want to find sub elements available on the first page. Is there any way to do this? I would appreciate if you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: With the array of <a> tags that you have in the WebElement List, parse them. Navigate to the first element of the list and do the same that you have done with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this elements, instead of creating List every time. Smth like this:

```
List<WebElement> var = null;
var.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")));
```

Answer (score 0):

All the links have anchor tag, so you can create a list of web elements based on the anchor tag locator and then print the text or the href tag(i.e. link URL) of each element.
Script-

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Launching sample website
    driver.get("{webpage URL}");

    //Get list of web-elements with tagName  - a
    List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    //Traversing through the list and printing its text along with link address
    for(WebElement link:allLinks){
        System.out.println(link.getText() + " - " + link.getAttribute("href"));
    }
}
```

Reference - [Get all links on a webpage using selenium and Java](http://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/get-all-links-in-a-webpage-selenium-webdriver-java.html)